# IRF540N application issues

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switches

[image]
I am fairly new to using MOSFET's in circuits and I am a little stuck. I want to use the IRF540N as a switch, which will receive a voltage to the gate, and 18-30 volts at the drain. I would like for the source to essentially follow the voltage of the drain as long as there is voltage being applied to the gate. I am having trouble getting it to work that way, I tried testing it with a power supply as seen in the picture but I keep getting unexpected behavior. Am I testing it wrong? Should I add resistors or anything else to achieve the desired results from the IRF540N?

datasheet: https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/IRF540N.pdf

attempted tests:
[image]

Comment: it LOOKS like you have the source connected to ground in both diagrams, and yet you want 20V at the source?  How would that work?

Comment: Yup -- if you have a load connected to the source, show it.  Please -- my head gets filled with nasty-smelling smoke just looking at your diagram on the left.

Comment: What's your actual application purpose?  Describe the nature of the load to be controlled, and what will produce the control signal.

Comment: okay i added the load and control source. I guess I was testing it wrong then. I just wanted to figure out the configuration that would give me the desired results at the source terminal before implementing it in my circuit

Comment: Your edit *confuses* the issue rather than clarifying it.  Are you trying to simply turn this thing on and off?  Or are you trying to vary the voltage? Is there any forced commonality between the pi control circuit and the load circuit, or do they have independent isolated supplies?  Could you switch the low side with an N-FET instead???

Comment: Oh sorry, but yes essentially I just want to turn the load on or off. In other words I don't want it to see the voltage coming from the power supply until it receives the control signal. The pi control circuit do have a forced commonality. It can be a low side or high side as long as the load wont see the voltage coming from the source

Comment: Actually to further clarify I need a switch between the positive supply and the load.

Comment: You want a high-side switch, figure 3 is closest to what you want. https://www.vishay.com/docs/70611/70611.pdf   I normally use an NPN instead of the N-channel level-shifter, then you need a resistor in series with the base.

Comment: *Why* do you need a high side switch?  If you want that, you're going to need to use an additional NFET or NPN to drive the gate of your PFET.  Otherwise you could just use a logic level NFET with sufficient current rating as a low side switch.

Comment: Well, I was thinking a high side switch would work better since the control voltage cant go above 10V (preferably less since its coming from a raspberry pi) and then the supply voltage is variable (around 20V). So from what I was reading for an NMOS the control voltage at the gate would have to be quite a bit higher than 20V to achieve a voltage at the load roughly the same as the voltage of the supply. The 'load' is a grounded circuit, and ideally I don't want it to receive power until the switch receives the proper control signal.

Comment: also, I am pretty new to using transistors as switches so I wasnt sure how to do a low side switch

Answer (score 1):

> *I would like for the source to essentially follow the voltage of the
> drain*

That's not going to happen: -

You have the source connected to 0 volts and given that the power source is also connected to 0 volts at its negative terminal then for it to do what you want it means that the power source is shorted out and it'll smoke.

Comment: So the 20V was shorted? Is that why the voltage at the source terminal was essentially the same as the voltage applied to the gate?

Comment: The 20 volts becomes shorted when the MOSFET turns on - it shorts out the 20 volts in attempt 1.

Comment: That makes sense. How could I implement a switch between the power source and a load then? Should a PMOS be used? How do you figure out what resistors should be used? If any?

Comment: Well, attempt 2 is the correct circuit if you want to switch current into the load and, given that the source is connected to 0 volts, you have to be mistaken about measuring 2 volts between source and 0 volts. Or, the resistor may have been (say) 1 ohm and such a large current was flowing that you measured a volt drop due to bad wiring.

Comment: okay thank you, maybe the wrong resistor was used since it wasn't checked